# Install SXA 1.7 on XP1 CD server

Tags: sxa, sitecore-install-framework

I've setup a XP1 Installation with CD and CM. I've installed the SXA and Powershell Extensions on my CM with the Installation Wizzard and here Its working I can open the site and edit content and view the content on the CM

I've inserted the Hostnames.

[image]
on the cm I can open the site

[image]

I don't know how to install the hole SXA on the CD, because I've no Installation Wizzard there Or I don't know how to open it.

What I've tried so far is to extract the installation files and copied only the content of the "files" folder direct into the CD website

[image]

I've edited the :C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreCd1.staging.com\App_Config\Include\Foundation\Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.config

and changed the database from master to web like in the installations decriped in the installation guide

but that seems not to work right, when I know call my site on my CD I get the following error:

[image]

SOLVED: Write Error in the host names :-/

Comment: Are you sure the hostnames are correctly inserted? In your screenshot, you have your CM twice ;)

Comment: @Gatogordo thx man that was it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the hostnames are correct. In your screenshot I can see the CM twice.

Remember you can use wildcards in the hostname: `sitecorec*1.staging.com` would cover both sitecorecm1.staging.com and sitecorecd1.staging.com